# HTML Email not sending properly When using CRON

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, cron, centos

Hi I am using codeigniter framework and CentOS. I am using a cron to send an html email , it calls to a php file from the cron , from the file i use ths command to call to a codegniter function

```
system("elinks -dump http://localhost/mailsender/index.php/mail/send/$email_job_id/");
```

from that i generate an html email .but the email html is not sending properly .

when i view the source of emil in my outlook , i can see ( this only a part of table )

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">Please check the Type Extension list.<br><br><table cellpadding="3D3D3D3D3=" D3="3D" D?="3D3D" 10="3D3D3D" ?="3D3D3D3D" st="3D3D3D3D3D" yle="3D3D3D3D3D3D&quot;border:1px" solidblack;border-collapse:collapse;?="">
<tr>
    <td style="3D3D3D3D3D3D&quot;border:1px" solidblack;?="">Model</td>
    <td style="3D3D3D3D3D3D&quot;border:1px" solidblack;?="">Description</td>
    <td style="3D3D3D3D3D3D&quot;border:1px" solidblack;?="">Et</td>
    <td style="3D3D3D3D3D3D&quot;border:1px" solidblack;?="">Option Codes</td>
    <td style="3D3D3D3D3D3D&quot;border:1px" solidblack;?="">Order numbers</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>

<tr><td style="3D3D3D3D3D3D&quot;border:1px" solidblack;?="">2E32</td><td style="3D3D=" 3D3D="3D" 3D3D="3D3D" ?bor="3D3D3D" der:="3D3D3D3D" 1px="3D3D3D3D3D" solidblack;?="">216D GRAN TOURER RHD</td><td style="3D3D3D3D3D3D&quot;border:1px" so="li=3D" d="3D3D" bl="3D3D3D" ac="3D3D3D3D" k;="3D3D3D3D3D" ?="">205,402,4UB,7LG</td><td style="3D3D3D3D3D3D&quot;border:1px" solidblack;?="">2=
20=3D
97=3D3D
23=3D3D3D
76=3D3D3D3D
</=3D3D3D3D3D></tr>
```

My Mail sending function

```
function send($id) {

    $this->load->library('email');

    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['useragent'] = 'GSPL';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.***';

    $config['smtp_user'] = '';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = '';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from("***");
    $this->email->reply_to("***");
    $this->email->subject("***");

    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $new_email_body = $this->create_email_body();
    $data->body = $new_email_body;

    $this->email->message($data->body);
    $this->email->to("*****");          
    $this->email->send();

    }
```

create_email_body function will call to a view with the data

```
<table cellpadding="10" style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;">Model</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;">Description</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;">Et</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;">Option Codes</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;">Order numbers</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        echo '<tr><td style="border:1px solid black;">'.$row["model"].'</td><td style="border:1px solid black;">'.$row["description"].'</td><td style="border:1px solid black;">'.$row["et"].'</td><td style="border:1px solid black;">'.$row["option_codes"].'</td><td style="border:1px solid black;">'.$row["order_numbers"].'</td></tr>';
    }

?>
    </tbody>
<table>
```

Is there any way to send the correctly formatted HTML . Thank you in advance .

**NOTE**

The email is sending correctly formatted when i run the below directly in the browser .

```
http://localhost/mailsender/index.php/mail/send/***/
```

Table source i can see in outlook

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">Please check the Type Extension list.<br><br><table cellpadding="10" style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;">Model</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;">Description</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;">Et</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;">Option codes</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;">Order numbers</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>

<tr><td style="border:1px solid black;">ABCD</td><td style="border:1px solid black;">test</td><td style="border:1px solid black;">ABC</td><td style="border:1px solid black;">222,222,22</td><td style="border:1px solid black;">22222,22222,2222</td></tr> </tbody>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you use system and elinks?

You could running the cronjob via the CLI:

```
php path/to/index.php mail send "some_id"
```

Did you also tried it with wget or curl?